# Proving that a sequence is between certain values at certain n

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm given that $a_1=1$, and for every $n \gt1, a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{a_{n}}$. I need to prove that $20 < a_{200} < 24$. I tried finding a limit at infinity setting both limits to $L$ ( for $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ but that gave me nothing useful. All I figured out was that this sequence is increasing..

Comment: You did a good job with the $\LaTeX$ but need to put it between dollar signs.  Please check that I got it right.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much I just edited a few parts that were off but I appreciate the help on Tex.

Comment: There is a $+1$ that vanished in the equation for $a_{n+1}$.  Should it be there?

Comment: I would be tempted to submit an Excel spreadsheet showing $a_{200}\approx 20.05927812$

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I was actually thinking of doing this on MATLAB but I'm supposed to (sadly) formally prove it.

Comment: I know Mathematica, and I believe MATLAB, handle rational numbers properly, so you can get an exact rational value for $a_{200}$.  The computation is a fine proof.  It is like being asked to prove that $2 \lt 1+1+1 \lt 4$.  The limit can't help-I can find increasing sequences with limit $\lt 24$ such that $a_{200} \lt 20$.  This sequence grows without limit, but very slowly, so you would need to bound it below and above.

Comment: Oh right! I think its possible to find a sequence larger than this with a limit of 25 or so, and another one smaller with a limit of 20 or so. Show that this $a_n$ is in between these two at certain values, then go on to show that by something similar to the squeeze theorem, its bounded. I'm not sure if this sounds reasonable, so any opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lower bound**:

Let's prove that $a_n>\sqrt{2n}$ for $n\geqslant 3$, other words:

$$
(a_n)^2>2n, \qquad (n \geqslant 3).
\tag{1}
$$

$a_2 = 1+1=2$.
First, $(a_3)^2 = (2+\frac{1}{2})^2 = 4+2+\frac{1}{4} > 2\cdot 3$.

Now, using math. induction, we will show, that 
$$(a_n)^2>2n \implies (a_{n+1})^2>2(n+1).$$ 
Yes, if $(a_n)^2>2n$, then
$$
(a_{n+1})^2 = \left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2 = (a_n)^2 + 2 + \left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2>2n+2=2(n+1).
$$
Statement $(1)$ is proved.

So, $a_{200}>\sqrt{2\cdot 200} = 20$.

---

**Upper bound**:

Let's prove that $a_n<\sqrt{\frac{13}{6}n}$ for $n\geqslant 3$, other words:
$$
(a_n)^2 < \frac{13}{6}n, \qquad (n \geqslant 3).
\tag{2}
$$
First, $(a_3)^2 = \left(2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 4+2+\frac{1}{4}<6+\frac{1}{2} = \frac{13}{6}\cdot 3$.

Using math. induction and $(1)$, we will show, that 
$$(a_n)^2<\frac{13}{6}n \implies (a_{n+1})^2<\frac{13}{6}(n+1).$$ 
Yes, if $(a_n)^2<13n/6$, then
$$
(a_{n+1})^2 = \left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2 = (a_n)^2 + 2 + \left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2<
\frac{13}{6}n + 2 + \frac{1}{2n} \leqslant  \frac{13}{6}n + 2+\frac{1}{6}  = \frac{13}{6}(n+1),
$$
since $(a_n)^2>2n\geqslant 6$, when $n\geqslant 3$.
Statement $(2)$ is proved.

So, $a_{200}<\sqrt{\frac{13}{6}\cdot 200} \approx 20.81666 <24$.

Comment: You beat me to it by 5 minutes!

Comment: Typos: "If $a_n^2 < 13n/6$", not "If $a_{n+1}^2 < 13n/6$" and  "$a_n^2 > 2n$", not "$a_n > 2n$".

Comment: @marty cohen, thank you for typos correction. I hope yu'll beat me next time. without doubts!

Comment: That's an awesome way to do it, but I'm stuck on why you chose sqrt(13/6 n). It just seems like a random number to me.

Comment: @TimG: If $2n$ is lower bound of $(a_n)^2$ (close to $(a_n)^2$), that intuitively is to search upper bound as
$$(2+s)n,$$
where $s$ is small value.
If $(a_n)^2<(2+s)n$, then

$$(a_{n+1})^2 = (a_n)^2+2+(1/a_n)^2<(2+s)n+2+\frac{1}{2n}\tag{1}$$

So, I choose such value $s$, that 
$$
2+\frac{1}{2n}\leqslant (2+s).\tag{2}
$$
Then I can continue estimation $(1)$:

$$
(1)... \leqslant (2+s)n + (2+s) =  (2+s)(n+1).
$$

It is easy to see, that for $n\geqslant 3$ we can choose $s=\frac{1}{6}$.
Then ineq. $(2)$ will be true: $2+\frac{1}{2n}\leqslant (2+\frac{1}{6})$.

$~~2+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{13}{6}$.

Comment: I follow everything up until equation (2). Is it saying that since (2+s)n is an upper bound of $(a_n)^2$ that the remainder term $2+\frac{1}{2n}$ must be approximated by (2+s)? I understand you put in 2n for $(a_n)$ because that maximizes the value of that piece, but I'm not sure why you isolated that bit and set it less than or equal to 2+s. Other than that, it's really clear and easy to follow.

Comment: Yes, @TimG, all I need here is to show that 
$$
a_n^2<(2+s)n \implies a_{n+1}^2<(2+s)(n+1) ~~~~\mbox{(induction step);} 
$$

Since 
$$
(2+s)(n+1) =(2+s)n+\color{green}{(2+s)}, \tag{A}
$$
$$
a_{n+1}^2 <(2+s)n+\color{green}{2+\dfrac{1}{2n}},~~~\mbox{(see (1))}\tag{B},
$$
then I want to choose such $s$, that $(B)<(A)$, other words
$$ 
\color{green}{2+\dfrac{1}{2n}}<\color{green}{(2+s)}. \tag{C}
$$

Inequality $(C)$ is true for $n\geqslant 3$, when $s=\dfrac{1}{6}$ (or bigger).

Answer (score 1):

This answer gives better bounds than the other two answers
and shows the true value of $a_n$.

In particular, 
I will show that
$$a_n 
= \sqrt{2n + \frac{\ln (n)}{2} + O(1)}
= \sqrt{2n}+ \frac{\ln (n)}{4\sqrt{2n}}+O(\frac1{\sqrt{n}})
$$

The key is to look at $a_n^2$ rather than $a_n$.

Let $b_n = a_n^2$.
Then
$b_1=1$,
$b_2=4$,
and
$b_{n+1}
=\left(a_n+\frac1{a_n}\right)^2
=a_n^2+2+\frac1{a_n^2} 
=b_n+2+\frac1{b_n} 
$.

Using this,
I will show that,
successively,
modulo possible errors,
that

$\begin{align}
b_n & > 2n\\
b_n &< b_k +(n-k)(2+\frac1{2k})  \quad\text{ (for } n > k)\\ 
b_n &< n(2+\frac1{6}) \quad\text{ (the previous line with } k=3) \\
b_n &< 2n+\frac12\ln(n-1) \\ 
b_n &> 2n+\frac12 \ln(n)-c 
\quad\text{ where }c\text{ is a positive constant}\\ 
b_n & = 2n + \frac{\ln (n)}{2} + O(1)\\
\end{align}
$

Note:
Numerical computations suggest that
$b_n - \left(2n + \frac{\ln (n)}{2}\right)
\to -0.2768...$,
$a_n - \left( \sqrt{2n}+ \frac{\ln (n)}{4\sqrt{2n}} \right)
\to 0$
and
$\sqrt{n}\left(a_n - \left( \sqrt{2n}+ \frac{\ln (n)}{4\sqrt{2n}} \right)\right)
\to -0.0979138$.
These results are therefore 
probably correct,
since they agree so well.

Since
$b_{n+1}
=b_n+2+\frac1{b_n} 
$,
$$b_{n+1} -b_n=2+\frac1{b_n} 
$$

Summing this from
$k$ to $n-1$,
$b_{n} -b_k
=\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \left(2+\frac1{b_j} \right)
=2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} 
 $,
or
$$b_{n} 
=b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} 
$$

This is the key formula.
First,
since the $b_j > 0$,
putting $k = 2$
 gives
$b_n > 2n$ for
$n > 2$.

Putting this *lower* bound for
$b_n$ into the formula
gives an *upper* bound for $b_n$.
The upper bound, in turn,
gives a better lower bound,
which, in turn,
gives an even better lower bound.

Setting $k=2$,
since $b_2=4$,
 gives
$$b_{n} = 2n+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} $$

As a first application of the formula,
since $b_n \ge 2n$
and the $b_n$ are increasing,

$\begin{align}
b_{n} 
&= b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} \\
&< b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_k} \\
&< b_k +(n-k)(2+\frac1{b_k}) \\
&< b_k +(n-k)(2+\frac1{2k}) \\ 
\end{align}
$

Setting $k=3$,
since $b_3 = 25/4$,

$\begin{align}
b_{n} 
&< \frac{25}{4} +(n-3)(2+\frac1{6}) \\
&= n(2+\frac1{6})-3\frac{13}{6}+\frac{25}{4} \\
&= n(2+\frac1{6})-\frac{78-75}{12}\\
&< n(2+\frac1{6}) \\
\end{align}
$

We can do even better.
Since
$ \frac1{j+1}
< \int_j^{j+1} \frac{dx}{x}
= \ln(j+1)-\ln(j)
< \frac1{j}
$,
$ \sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{j+1} 
= \sum_{j=k}^{n-1} (\ln(j+1)-\ln(j))
= \ln(n)-\ln(k)
 < \sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{j}
 $.

Therefore
$\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} 
<\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{2j}
=\frac12\sum_{j=k-1}^{n-2} \frac1{j+1}
<\frac12(\ln(n-1)-\ln(k-1)) 
$,
so
$$b_n
=b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} 
< b_k +2(n-k)+\frac12(\ln(n-1)-\ln(k-1)) 
$$

Setting $k=2$,
for $n > 2$,
$b_n
< 2n+\frac12\ln(n-1)
< 2n+\frac12\ln(n) 
$.

Putting this back in the sum,
and using
$\frac1{1+x} > 1-x$,

$\begin{align}
b_n 
&=b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{b_j} \\
&> b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{2j+\frac12\ln(j)} \\
&= b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{2j}\frac1{1+\ln(j)/(4j)} \\ 
&> b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{2j}\left(1-\frac{\ln(j)}{4j}\right) \\ 
&> b_k +2(n-k)+\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{2j}
-\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac{\ln(j)}{8j^2} \\ 
\end{align}
$

Since the last sum converges,
if
$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(j)}{8j^2}
= c_k$,
and since
$ 
 \sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac1{j} 
> \ln(n)-\ln(k)
$,
$$b_n
> b_k +2(n-k)+\frac12 (\ln(n)-\ln(k))-c_k
$$

Putting $k=2$,
we see that
$b_n > 2n+\frac12 \ln(n)-(\ln(2)+c_2) $.

These bounds on $b_n$
imply that
$b_n = 2n + \frac{\ln (n)}{2} + O(1)$.

Since
$a_n = \sqrt{b_n}$,

$\begin{align}
a_n
&= \sqrt{2n + \frac{\ln (n)}{2} + O(1)}\\
&= \sqrt{2n}\sqrt{1 + \frac{(\ln (n))/2 + O(1)}{2n}}\\
&= \sqrt{2n}\left(1 + \frac{\ln (n) + O(1)}{8n}+O(\frac{(\ln(n)+O(1))^2}{n^2})\right)\\
&= \sqrt{2n}+ \frac{\ln (n)}{4\sqrt{2n}}+O(\frac1{\sqrt{n}})+O(\frac{\ln^2(n)}{n^{3/2}})\\
&= \sqrt{2n}+ \frac{\ln (n)}{4\sqrt{2n}}+O(\frac1{\sqrt{n}})\\
\end{align}
$

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to submit my answer.
It's a little different from Oleg567's,
but the results are the same.

I first try to estimate the growth of $a_n$.
From the desired bounds,
it looks like it might be of order
$\sqrt{n}$.

Suppose
$a_n
=c\sqrt{n}
$.
Then
$c\sqrt{n}+1/(c\sqrt{n})
=c\sqrt{n+1}
=c\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+1/n}
\approx c\sqrt{n}(1+1/(2n)) 
= c\sqrt{n}+c/(2\sqrt{n}) 
$
or
$1/(c\sqrt{n})
\approx c/(2\sqrt{n})
$
or
$1/c \approx c/2$
or
$c \approx \sqrt{2}$.

It therefore looks like
$a_n \approx \sqrt{2n}$.

Suppose $a_n > \sqrt{2n}$.
Then
$a_{n+1}
> \sqrt{2n}+1/\sqrt{2n}
$.

To show
$a_{n+1} > \sqrt{2(n+1)}$,
we need
$\sqrt{2n}+1/\sqrt{2n}
> \sqrt{2(n+1)}$.
Squaring both sides,
this is
$2n+2+1/(2n)
> 2(n+1)
$
which is true.

Setting $n=200$,
$a_{200} > \sqrt{400} = 20$.

Suppose
$a_n \le \sqrt{(2+k)n}$ for some $k$.
Then, since
$a_n^2 > 2n$,
$a_{n+1}^2
=a_n^2+2+1/a_n^2
< (2+k)n+2+1/(2n)
$
and for this to be
$\le (2+k)(n+1)$
we need
$(2+k)n+2+1/(2n)
\le (2+k)(n+1)$
or
$2+1/(2n) \le 2+k$
or
$1/(2n)\le k$.
This will certainly be true for
large enough $n$.

We have
$a_2 = 2$, $a_3 = 5/2$,
and $a_4 = 5/2+2/5 = 29/10$.
For $n=3$,
we want
$25/4 \le 3(2+k)=6+3k$
or
$1/4 \le 3k$
or $k \ge 1/12$.
Since we also want
$k \ge 1/(2n) = 1/6$,
we can use $k = 1/6$.